# Python tkinter pack before?

Tags: python

Does anyone know what argument the -before parameter of the tkinter pack package manager takes?
I couldn't find an example of it on the Internet, it's missing.
I do not understand: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/pack.html#M9
Thanks!

```
 import tkinter as tk

 root = tk.Tk()
 root.title('Before example')
 root.geometry("300x250")
 root.configure(bg='#a8c3bc')

 label = tk.Label(root, text="What does before do?", bg="#a8c3bc")
 label.pack()

 button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Clicking", bg="green", fg="white")
 button1.pack()

 button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Clicking", bg="red", fg="white")
 button2.pack()

 root.mainloop()

# pack(before=int)
```

pack(before=str)
pack(before=boolean)'''

Comment: `.pack()`'s `before=` and `after=` options require another widget, which in normal use would be another child of the same parent that contains the widget being packed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, I translated it into Hungarian, but unfortunately I don't understand it either. Is writing a code a big ask? I always understand that.

Comment: Üdvözöllek! Esetleg ha valakit érdekel a megoldás kódja, itt lehet megnézni. Itt kaptam egzakt választ:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/python-tkinter-pack-before?comment=195939